# How can I resolve inaccuracies in 3D object measurements using single camera calibration with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have calibrated my single camera (webcam) and obtained it's internal and external parameters via the chessboard calibration method by open-cv. The webcam is completely fixed and the depth of the camera is also constant and known value.

Now I also have the camera z distance and I have used this value to multiply the pixel points by the inverse of the internal parameter matrix. So I get the correct points.

At first, i have done the camera calibration and obtained all the parameters like mtx,dist,rvecs and tvecs.

Then i have made the image points homogenous and multiplied them with the inverse of camera internal matrix.

```
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
img_end = internal_inverse.dot(np.array(point_end))
img_end *= depth_value
```

Since, i already know the depth value. I am multiplying the coordinates with image z coordinate.

I also have converted the external points at the start which have been shown in the open cv calibration tutorial to mm by multiplying the chessboard square length.

```
objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:6, 0:9].T.reshape(-1, 2)*square_size
```

Then I converted the camera points to world points by rotation and translation obtained from cv Rodrigues function. Since the result was not right so I measured the distance between two points and then multiplied it with a number such that I got the correct value.

```
world_coords_end = R_inv.dot(img_end) + R_inv.dot(t_neg)
```

I have saved the matrix value and loaded it in my other program where I want to measure a box length and the result was not correct. So can anybody please guide me on what is wrong or if my scale factor is wrong?

I have deprojected my points from world to pixel, which match the original values. Error is 0.02 per cent.

```
errorx = np.mean([(abs(jx - ix)/jx)*100 for (ix, _), (jx, _) in zip(reprojected_points, imgpoints_checkproject)])
```

This is the code for measuring the error value.
Also, the points are homogenous and only I have done the above calculations.

I have tried full calibration and got all the values but the results that I get are not correct.
The calibration results look like this
This is the image of the chessboard with distance image, here white is the image coordinate and the other is the world coordinate.

[image]

Comment: Can you put all your code up into one block so others can run it?

Comment: @DrBwts, i cannot paste everything here. But i have added all the imortant steps that i have done. Do you need any info. I did some edits